# How can we monitor/ensure penetration from HTTP Request/communication bucket?

Tags: web-testing, penetration-testing

Website security testing is an imp area of testing. How can we ensure the penetration of important info from HTTP request bucket?

There are many tools which can show us http request bucket but how can we ensure penetration from it?

What should be techniques to test this area?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your questions but if you have bucket for example in AWS S3 that host your website, you can define logging folder that will save and monitor all access to it, you can review hacking attempts and other security related issues. additional tool is AWS cloudtrail which records all activity and test the security.